# Replicating a Specific Terminal Appearance in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal, vscode-extensions, color-scheme

I have a specific terminal appearance that I'd like to replicate in Visual Studio Code (VSCode). I have attached an image of the terminal with the desired colors and settings.

I've tried modifying the settings.json file in VSCode, specifically the "workbench.colorCustomizations" section, but I haven't been able to achieve the exact look.

Here are the color settings I'm aiming for:

```
  "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
        "terminal.background": "#231F20",
        "terminal.foreground": "#D9D8D8",
        "terminalCursor.background": "#D9D8D8",
        "terminalCursor.foreground": "#D9D8D8",
        "terminal.ansiBlack": "#231F20",
        "terminal.ansiBlue": "#009DDC",
        "terminal.ansiBrightBlack": "#737171",
        "terminal.ansiBrightBlue": "#009DDC",
        "terminal.ansiBrightCyan": "#85CEBC",
        "terminal.ansiBrightGreen": "#00853E",
        "terminal.ansiBrightMagenta": "#98005D",
        "terminal.ansiBrightRed": "#EE2E24",
        "terminal.ansiBrightWhite": "#FFFFFF",
        "terminal.ansiBrightYellow": "#FFD204",
        "terminal.ansiCyan": "#85CEBC",
        "terminal.ansiGreen": "#00853E",
        "terminal.ansiMagenta": "#98005D",
        "terminal.ansiRed": "#EE2E24",
        "terminal.ansiWhite": "#D9D8D8",
        "terminal.ansiYellow": "#FFD204"
    },
```

I'm also using the Material Theme Palenight High Contrast color theme for the overall VSCode appearance.

Additionally, I've included my entire settings.json file for reference.

Could someone please guide me on how to configure VSCode to achieve the exact terminal appearance as shown in the attached image?

Thank you!

[Image of the terminal ❤️❤️❤️❤️](https://i.stack.imgur.com/87KDe.png)

Comment: next time link to the original image resource instead of copying the image. and link to the location you got the image from. i.e. https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/terminal/appearance. Also, most of the explanation of how to reproduce that setup is stated literally right under the image...